# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx/Observable$OnSubscribe

Tags: java

I create a project named RxJava to demostrate the usage of API of RxJava, below is the content of the java file.

```
package com.limx.reactive;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;



public class CreateDemo {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> observer) {
                try {
                    if (!observer.isUnsubscribed()) {
                        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                            observer.onNext(i);
                        }
                        observer.onCompleted();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    observer.onError(e);
                }
            }
         } ).subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(Integer item) {
                    System.out.println("Next: " + item);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable error) {
                    System.err.println("Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    System.out.println("Sequence complete.");
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Then I compile with

```
limxtop@IdeaPad:~/test/RxJava$ javac -d ./bin -classpath ~/libs/rxjava-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar src/com/limx/reactive/CreateDemo.java
```

There are some coressponding class file generated in bin directory after compile successfully.

But when I execute the class file with

```
limxtop@IdeaPad:~/test/RxJava$ java -classpath ./bin com.limx.reactive.CreateDemo
```

Exception occur

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx/Observable$OnSubscribe
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3035)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3005)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1771)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rx.Observable$OnSubscribe
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

It seems that it can't find the inner class "OnSubscribe" in class "Observable", right? but why and how to resolve it?

/********************** add further questions ****************/

```
limxtop@IdeaPad:~/test/RxJava$ java -classpath ~/libs/rxjava-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:./bin/ com.limx.reactive.CreateDemo
Next: 1
Next: 2
Next: 3
Next: 4
Sequence complete.
```

The command above work successfully, but now I have further quesitions.

1. The exception says that it can't find the definition of Observable$OnSubscribe rather than Observable which means that Observable class is resolved, so why rxjava-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar needed?
2. Should the order of classpath be consistent with the import chain? otherwise, how to explain it doesn't work when change the order.

here are the files in bin directory:

```
limxtop@IdeaPad:~/test/RxJava/bin/com/limx/reactive$ ll
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 2 limxtop limxtop 4096 May 29 13:03 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 limxtop limxtop 4096 May 29 13:03 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 limxtop limxtop 1226 May 29 13:03 CreateDemo$1.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 limxtop limxtop 1062 May 29 13:03 CreateDemo$2.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 limxtop limxtop  630 May 29 13:03 CreateDemo.class
```

Comment: Try using `-classpath bin/*`

Comment: I have tried, but it doesn't work still.
limxtop@IdeaPad:~/test/RxJava$ java -classpath ./bin/* com.limx.reactive.CreateDemo
Error: Could not find or load main class com.limx.reactive.CreateDemo

Comment: Actually -classpath bin/* is wrong.  For explanation and more detail informations see section Understanding class path wildcards at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `rxjava-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` to your classpath too since it contains the RxJava (`Observable`, etc.) classes:

```
java -classpath ~/libs/rxjava-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:./bin com.limx.reactive.CreateDemo
```

In case you are working on Windows, you need to use `;` instead of `:` as classpath separator.

**Update**

Be aware that the expansion of `~/` to your HOME directory (which is done by the shell not by the `java` executable) does not work when it occurs somewhere in the middle of the `-classpath` declaration. You should better use a fully qualified path or something like `${HOME}/libs/rxjava-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT`, which is more reliable.

Comment: limxtop@IdeaPad:~/test/RxJava$ java -classpath ./bin:~/libs/rxjava-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.limx.reactive.CreateDemo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx/Observable$OnSubscribe

Comment: But when I change the order of the value of classpath, it work normally, which make me confused.

limxtop@IdeaPad:~/test/RxJava$ java -classpath ~/libs/rxjava-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:./bin/ com.limx.reactive.CreateDemo
Next: 1
Next: 2
Next: 3
Next: 4
Sequence complete.

Comment: @Saint Probably it's the missing slash. Could you try `-classpath ./bin/:~/libs/rxjava-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: No, I have tried this after I changed the order to work successfully.

Comment: Strange... What is in your `./bin` directory? Is there also an `rx` package?

Comment: No, please refer to the question section, at the end of which I have add the files information in the bin directory. The informations can't formatted to read friendly in the comment section.

Comment: I tried it myself with a compatible rxjava library (http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cio.reactivex%7Crxjava%7C1.3.0%7Cjar). The problem is, that the `~` is not resolved after the colon. There is no problem when you put it at the beginning or if you substitute it with your real HOME directory, e.g. `java -classpath ./bin:/home/<username>/libs/rxjava-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. I changed my answer accordingly.